# "One verb with different prefixes" Structure

Tags: verb, prefix

I was wondering about **a verb which has different prefixes**.

How should I properly search for grammar rules and became more familiar with their meanings, particularly in **Deutsch Sprache**?

For instance, the main word is **bauen** and its derivatives:

- aufbauen
- umbauen
- anbauen
- verbauen
- ausbauen
- etc.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you just want to know a search term?

Comment: Oh, and your *bauen* list is incomplete, there's also *erbauen*, *bebauen*, *vorbauen*, *überbauen*, etc etc **all with their own tricky non-obvious meanings**

Comment: Ich denke, er möchte wissen wie das linguistische Phänomen heißt, dass ein Verbstamm mit unterschiedlichen Vorsilben unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben kann.

Comment: In your examples there is not a single verb with multiple prefixes. You listed five different verbs, each of them with just one prefix. Verbs with multiple prefixes have two or more prefixes (like *ausverkaufen, anerkennen* or *beeindrucken* with two prefixes, or *mitveranlassen* with three prefixes).

Comment: Yes, [@Janka](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23885/janka).

Comment: [@Javatasse](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/33503/javatasse), genau, das ist richtig. Ich frage mich auf das linguistische Phänomen.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortbildung

Comment: This phenomenon is not restricted to German. So to me it is not clear if the question is about the linguistic phenomenon in general or about German verbs of this kind.

Comment: You are still thinking wrong. It is not **one** verb with different prefixes. They are many different and distinctive verbs. They just derive from the same other verb, but they all stand on the same level as all other verbs. Each of them is listed separately in a dictionary, and each of them has its own meaning. A German native speaker doesn't treat *aufbauen, verbauen, ausbauen* etc. together in any manner.

Comment: Meaning is easy - grab a dictionary and search for that particular word.

Comment: @TarasDubrava As for your specific question, just note that not all of your examples are of the same breed. Most linguists would classify _verbauen_ as a Präfixverb, the others as Partikelverben (the terminology is not entirely uniform). These are the terms of art you can look for if you are interested in the (morphological) details. I agree with the other commentators, though, that this of interest mostly to linguists; as a learner, you will generally have to study each and every Präfix-/Partikelverb individually, along with their distinct valence patterns.

Comment: [@johnl](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/31256/johnl), thank you so much for your response. You are there first adequate commentator so far. I do not know if it makes any sense now, however, I just wanted to find a list/table with all those "prefix + verb" structures and study them group by group, for instance firstly get to know "kaufen" and its "similarities", then "bauen", "arbeiten", "sagen", "laden" etc.

Comment: After the significant change of the question I think it's better to create a new one because this question has been put on hold and it doesn't look that you are going to get an answer here.

Comment: @Eller Wouldn't such a new question be closed as duplicated?

Comment: @Marzipanherz No, if you'd delete the old question. But this one was reopend, so it's doesn't matter anymore :)

Comment: @Eller it does, because [the duplicate](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46245/verbs-with-a-common-root) was posted and answered already.

Comment: Locking this instance of the question in its old state to contain the chaos. If you feel that anything said here is of relevance, please post it on the [new question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46245).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want to know. As far as I understand you, you are talking about something that is neither specific for German language, nor for verbs. I think, you are just talking about [word formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_formation) (the act of creating new words from already existing ones) ([Wortbildung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortbildung) in German).

Creating new words by adding prefixes, interfixes or suffixes ("affixes" as general term) is called [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation) ([Derivation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(Linguistik)) in German). It exists in English too, and is not limited to verbs.

English examples (verbs):

> de + form → deform
>   in + form → inform
>   per + form → perform
>   re + form → reform

Note, that *deform, inform, perform* etc. are distinct words. They are not forms of *form*! And the same is true for *aufbauen, umbauen, anbauen* etc. in German. They are distinct words.

---

**Non-verb examples:**

English:

> im + possible → impossible
>   extra + terrestrial → extraterrestrial
>   over + dressed → overdressed
>   mid + night → midnight
>   sub + marine → submarine

German:

> ab + Leitung → Ableitung
>   durch + Schnitt → Durchschnitt
>   un + möglich → unmöglich

---

### Addendum

Yesterday evening you edited your question and changed it. Now you ask for a list or table of such verbs. This was not part of your initial question. It is **strongly discouraged** to change a question this way! Editing is for correction of typos, not for changing the question!

But anyway. Here is your table: [Liste deutscher Präfixe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Pr%C3%A4fixe)

Comment: _Editing is for correction of typos, not for changing the question!_ Just for the records: editing is for clarification of a question as well. Your addendum reads a little grumpy, which I don't understand. As a high rep user you should know that an _unclear_ question can change to any degree between _not at all_ and _dramatically_.

Comment: Ich habe diese Frage eingefroren und die neue wiederaufgemacht, um das Chaos kleinzuhalten. Wenn Du möchtest, kannst Du eine Antwort auf die neue Frage schreiben, oder eine passende Frage mit dieser Antwort als Selbst-Antwort schreiben. Ansonsten gilt, was Marzipanherz gesagt hat: Wer unklare Fragen beantwortet, muss mit dem Risiko leben, dass er die Antwort nach Klarstellung ungültig wird.