# Verbs with a common root

Tags: verb, prefix

I was wondering about verbs which share the same root.

I would like to find a list/table/graphic/scheme/explanation where all those maybe "most known" verbs are described. Since I am not a German native, I do not know how properly define my request. Can you help me, please?

My examples so far are

- **bauen** - aufbauen, umbauen, anbauen, verbauen, ausbauen, etc.
- **laden** - einladen, aufladen, abladen etc.
- **arbeiten** - bearbeiten, zuarbeiten etc.

How should I properly threat them and become more familiar with their meanings, particularly in der Deutschen Sprache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if something like that exists specifically for learners. (I have some doubts, though. Quite frankly, this strikes me as an almost masochistic learning strategy: You would study extremely similar German lexems with widely differing meanings. Normally, this is the exact type of scenario that learners - me included - try to avoid when studying a foreign language.)

That being said, one book that does come to my mind is the (somewhat but not overly technical) *Helbig/Schenkel*, Wörterbuch zur Valenz und Distribution deutscher Verben, 7th ed. 1983. This is a dictionary of around 500 common verbs with their valence patterns. The entries do not always (though mostly) include definitions, but they all include simple example sentences/phrases. The dictionary is grouped by word families (e.g. *arbeiten* is followed by *bearbeiten, einarbeiten, überarbeiten, verarbeiten*), which, if I'm understanding you correctly, is what you're looking for.

(It appears that there is a preview available through Google Books, at https://books.google.de/books?id=KHgqcUKjgkoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de.)

P.S.: You could also use *cannoo.net*'s wildcard search feature and just enter some verbs you are interested in. A search for "*bauen" returns [this remarkable list of entries](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/Search/Controller?features=&lang=de&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive&service=canooNet&dispatch=canooNet&darj=0&input=*bauen&formInput=*bauen&resultId=99ff7c), for example.

Comment: +1, very helpful answer.

Comment: I'd too say learn verbs because you need them, not because they look similar.

Comment: Well, this could be a strategy to implicitly learn the meaning of the prefixes. But be aware that you will very hard times to find patterns in the meaning of the prefixes!

Comment: Danke Ihnen all, [johnl](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/31256/johnl), [@RHa](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26847/rha) und [@jonathan.scholbach](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15393/jonathan-scholbach)